# .imag Function for Complex Numbers

Tags: python

I learnt a function to display the imaginary part of a complex number & that is **.imag**
But when I was practising it, look what I found:

```
print(5-5j.imag)  #>>>0.0
print((5-5j).imag)#>>>-5.0
print(2+4j.imag)  #>>>6.0
print((2+4j).imag)#>>>4.0
```

What's happening with the output in the 1st & 2nd case?

Comment: I believe this question would be more suitable to stackoverflow.

Comment: @joseville Yes but I, unfortunately, got blocked frm asking ques:(

Comment: Why are you surprised that `5 - 5j.imag` is zero?

Comment: Because I thought that it 5-5j would be considered as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second and third `print` statements you're doing:

`a + bj.imag` = `a + (bj.imag)` = `a + b`

That is, you're taking the imaginary part of `bj` (which is `b`), then you're adding it to `a`. The result is that you print `a + b`.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions that are likely to get closed.  This one is not asking for a code review, and this answer isn't a review of the code, so you are just wasting resources with this.